# How to find a place id in Google Maps API if city has an identical name as region, province or municipality

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google places API I am trying to fetch place_id's. I have issues when trying to fetch a `place_id` when multiple parts of the place location have the same name. For example: The city Utrecht (in the Netherlands) lies in the municipality of Utrecht, Which lies in the province of Utrecht. They all have the same name.

When I [fetch Utrecht from the places service](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Utrecht) it returns the `place_id` for city (which is the default for maps incase there are multiple options)

I found a hack/solution to fetch the administrative areas: adding localised name of the thing i'm trying to fetch. For example I can use [Gemeente(municipality)](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Utrecht%20gemeente) or [Provincie(province)](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Utrecht%20pronvicie)

Is there a way to request specifically the type of region I want to fetch from the API?
I see that the places API has all this information, but sofar my attempts to fetch the `place_id` for the `administrative_area_level_2` or `administrative_area_level_1` without modifying the address are futile. 
My "fix" works for the Netherlands but I have 12 more European countries with similar issues hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

The most common solution is using the reverse geocoding with a [result type filter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding).

For example, your sample request for Utrecht returns the following coordinate 52.09073739999999,5.1214201

Now use reverse geocoding with result type.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.09073739999999%2C5.1214201&result_type=administrative_area_level_1&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This returns place ID ChIJPzM8M01oxkcRsFwejVreAAM for admin area level 1

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.09073739999999%2C5.1214201&result_type=administrative_area_level_2&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This returns place ID ChIJA9Xkz5BoxkcRzAM9YkCZGTs for admin area level 2

Hope it helps!